Laravel 11 configuring locale does not work
I have configured locale in config/app.php as the following:
'locale' => env('APP_LOCALE', 'hu'),
'fallback_locale' => env('APP_FALLBACK_LOCALE', 'en'),
'faker_locale' => env('APP_FAKER_LOCALE', 'en_US'),

Now when I write out the locale in the view I got "en".
{{App::currentLocale()}}

Why isn't this configuration option working?

may be in env file its set to en . if not clear config

@JohnLobo Thanks, it works now. I wonder why we have 2 places to set these values. Can you add it as an answer?

Environment Configuration

Laravel's default .env file contains some common configuration values
that may differ based on whether your application is running locally
or on a production web server. These values are then read by the
configuration files within the config directory using Laravel's env
function.
It is often helpful to have different configuration values based on
the environment where the application is running. For example, you may
wish to use a different cache driver locally than you do on your
production server.

If you want to set a default configuration that remains consistent across all environments, you can add it to the app.php file and remove the APP_LOCALE entry from the .env file. This way, you won't need to specify it in two different places.
